# Envio de formulário apenas clicando no radio button

Tags: javascript

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Observem os seguintes campos de formulário:

```
input type="radio" name="pagto" value="A"
input type="radio" name="pagto" value="B"
input type="radio" name="pagto" value="C"
input type="radio" name="pagto" value="D"
```

Notem que o "name" é o mesmo e a variável está no "value", conforme o padrão.

O que preciso: Ao clicar em um radio, o envio do formulário já acontece. Não quero usar o botão "submit", quero que o envio seja no momento do clique no radio e que TODOS os campos do formulário sejam enviados.

Comment: Sei que não é essa a sua pergunta (e por isso estou só comentando), mas eu diria que fazer o envio do formulário pelo clique no Radio Button é uma *má ideia*. Não sei os detalhes do sistema que está construindo, mas esse componente permite ao usuário fazer uma escolha que as vezes pode ser suficientemente importante (exemplo: qual opção de frete a pagar?) para que lhe seja permitido pensar a respeito e até mesmo alterar a escolha inicial. [...]

Comment: [...] Além do mais, tradicionalmente esse envio imediato não é o comportamento padrão, e certamente não vai ser esperado pela maioria dos usuários (ainda mais se forem recém-chegados ao seu sistema). Assim, você pode causar mais problemas do que facilidades. Sugiro não fazer isso, ou ao menos avaliar essa opção com alguns usuários antes de colocá-la em produção.

Answer (score 3):

Precisas de adicionar um oscultador do evento `change`. Também daria com `click` mas `change` é mais correto semânticamente e depois fazeres `form.submit()` quando esse evento fôr detectato.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
[].forEach.call(radios, function (radio) {
    radio.addEventListener('change', function () {
        document.querySelector('form').submit();
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0gkhygqx/

Se já souberes qual é o elemento `form` podes fazer como [o @ctgPi sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69117/envio-de-formul%C3%A1rio-apenas-clicando-no-radio-button/69118#comment141233_69118), senão podes usar isto (http://jsfiddle.net/0gkhygqx/1/) que procura o elemento `form` ao qual esse `input` pertence.

```
// isto fica dentro do event handler
var form = (function (el) {
    while (el.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'form') el = el.parentNode;
    return el;
})(e.target);
form.submit();
```

Comment: +1, mas não seria melhor fazer algo tipo `var form = document.querySelector('form');`, `var radios = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');` e `form.submit();`? Assim fica mais fácil de ajeitar no dia que o @Washington tiver mais de um formulário na página dele.

Comment: @ctgPi tens razão, juntei essa ideia e outra variante.